# How to access variables inside inner class

Tags: android, variables, kotlin

I have a inner class that reads OBD Data. How can I read the variables from a CsvWriter helper class so I can export them?

Should I pass the data as an argument to the method that exports the csv?

Is it possible to read the value from the CsvWrite class something like ObdListenService.connectedthread.rpmCommmand.formattedResult()?

```
class ObdListenService(context: Context, handler: Handler) {

   .....
    private inner class ConnectedThread() : Thread() {

        init {
            rpmCommand = RPMCommand () 
        }

        override fun run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) {
               val rpm = rpmCommand.formattedResult() 
               CsvWriter.export(rpm)   // is this correct?
            }
        }   
    }
```

```
class CsvWriter() {

    fun csvWrite(data : String ) {
    val row = data
       csvWriter().open(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + File.separator + "data.csv") {
            writeRow(row)
            println("position data is added")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: To do that, you would have to make the inner class public with `rpCommand` public aswell. I think, this class chaining does not look good and gives a vague idea about the parent class responsibility.